# When the body of a child shows signs of puberty, but the mind is not

Tags: children

It is well known that a matur child get mukallaf: it will need to perform acts of worship and it's actions are recorded.

But what in case of a child who first of all has the look of a higher age, but the mind of a child of lower age? The child's action differ without clear lines, from action of a person who can reason to those of a child that is still foolish in its actions.
In other words is there a modern description of conditions of maturity?

Comment: I don't understand your question properly. A person who reaches puberty but is foolish or wasteful has certain restrictions regarding financial dealings but there is no difference regarding their acts of worship or deeds. This is discussed under the keywords رشد and سفه and the verses  [4:5-6](https://quran.com/4/5-6?translations=20).